# kafka-node can i create topic with config retention.ms

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, retention

I have a situation in my coding to create a topic in nodejs using Kafka-node V1.3, but the created topics should have custom retention.ms param, I don't want to use brokers config retention.ms as it's for all the topics.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's possible, according to [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node#createtopicstopics-cb)

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node');
var client = new kafka.KafkaClient();

var topicsToCreate = [{
  topic: 'foo',
  partitions: 5,
  replicationFactor: 3,
  // Optional set of config entries
  configEntries: [
    {
      name: 'retention.ms',
      value: '1000000'
    }
  ]
}];

client.createTopics(topicsToCreate, (error, result) => {
  // result is an array of any errors if a given topic could not be created
});
```